# phase mod x freq mod equivalence

Tags: modulation

do any of you know how to convert a FM index to a phase mod index equivalent considering they both have the same carrier and modulator frequency? Is it even possible?

This is in respect for sound synthesis and I'm talking about one sinusoid modulating another sinusoidal oscillator.

I'm being able to get very similar sounds with these parameters:

FM: carrier freq 200Hz, modulator freq 480Hz, index 400*

- this means the carrier freq oscillates 400Hz up then back to original frequency and then down 400Hz and back 480 times a second

Phase Mod: carrier freq 200Hz, modulator freq 480Hz, index pi/4 **

** this index means the phase goes up 1/8 of a cycle and then back, down the same amount and back to the original point

FM and Phase Mod are clearly two independent processes, but I've seen people mention it can be equivalent, but I've never read anything that would tell me how to get the same results with both. So I don't know if it can really be done even if it sounds practically the same thing or if I just got lucky.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phase is the integral (w.r.t. time) of frequency.  and they are definitely **not** two independent processes.  back in, i dunno, the 30s, Armstrong implemented FM for the first time using AM and a synchronized carrier that was 90° out of phase with the AM.  so he was first accomplishing phase modulation (PM) out of AM (for which they had the existing technology - they didn't really have VCOs back in that day), then he implemented FM out of the PM by integrating the audio modulation signal and applying that to the PM modulation input.

this is all in a basic communications systems textbook like that of AB Carlson.

Comment: so how can one convert the modulation index to get exact same sound synthesis for the same carrier and modulation frequency? I can't find anything about it. I got this similar results I mentioned in the original post by pure accident. thanks

Comment: are you talking about FM synthesis of musical tones?  like Chowning and the Yamaha DX7?

Comment: yep, exactly. By the way, I was told DX7 uses PM and not FM. Cheers

Comment: okay, so think of $$ \sin( \theta(t) ) = \sin\left( 2 \pi \int_0^t f(u) \ du + \theta(0) \right) $$  or  $$ \sin\left( 2 \pi \int_0^t I \cdot x(u) \ du + \theta(0) \right) $$ where $x(t) \le 1$ is your modulating signal.  and $I$ is the modulation index.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not good at the math and needed a more straightforward formula convert the index from one case to the other considering same carrier & mod freqs - where the index in FM is in Hz, and is in radians in PM. What you wrote seems to be what this link also says http://moinsound.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/frequency-modulation-or-phase-modulation-synthesizer-technologies/ or so I believe, but if it is it doesn't get me there yet. Thanks anyhow

Comment: okay let's try $$ \sin\left( \omega_C t + 2 \pi \int_0^t I_\text{FM} \cos(\omega_M t + \theta_M) \ du + \theta_C(0)  \right) = \sin\left( \omega_C t + 2 \pi I_\text{PM} \sin(\omega_M t + \theta_M) \ du + \theta_C(0)  \right) $$

Comment: sorry, still about the same thing for me and not much diferent from what's in http://moinsound.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/frequency-modulation-or-phase-modulation-synthesizer-technologies/ which was what got me wondering about this in the first place.

I was hoping for something like Ifm = formula(IPm) - fm's index as a function of pm's index and vice versa. I know I don't have the math knowledge to solve it from this information and I'm sorry, but I had the idea it could be simpler than that. If it can't, it's ok, thanks anyway. Cheers

Comment: it's pretty simple if you look at the two sides of the equation and identify what is in common on each side.  can you compute an integral?

Comment: looks like i fucked up the expression and cannot edit that comment anymore.  try: $$ \sin\left(\omega_C t + 2 \pi \int_0^t I_\text{FM} \cos(\omega_M u + \theta_M) du + \theta_C \right) = \sin\left(\omega_C t + I_\text{PM} \sin(\omega_M t + \theta_M) + \theta_C \right) $$  the relationship between $I_\text{FM}$ and $I_\text{PM}$ is quite simple.

Comment: Your formula is clearer than the link I sen (seems to be the same, but is more detailed). So, I guess I've managed to understand all the variables, the tricky part is the integral for sure, I can't compute it myself :P Anyway, here's another link http://cnyack.homestead.com/files/modulation/modfmpm.htm I may be wrong, but it seems it is saying they're different things. Any thouhgts to add up? Well, I'll see if some friend can help me out with the integral and I'm gonna accept your answer. Thanks a lot for your help and attention.